# "Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/",

Tags: rest-api

I am trying to consume sales force rest api service in my java application.At that time i am getting this error.

"Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/"

I tested in advanced rest client with required values.It is giving output.While consuming same in my java code.It is returning this error

Please observe my source code

```
String resourceListUrl = "https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v26.0/"
url                    = new URL(resourceListUrl)
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection()
con.setDoOutput(true)
con.setDoInput(true)
con.setRequestMethod("GET")

con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken)
con.setRequestProperty("accept", "application/json")    

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))

while ((resourceLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    resourceList.append(resourceLine)
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks
Anuradha

Comment: 401 error refers to invalid access token, refresh your access token then try. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=intro_understanding_oauth_endpoints.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fintro_understanding_oauth_endpoints.htm|SkinName=webhelp

Comment: i tried with same accesstoken in advanced Rest client browser.It is giving output.It is not returning any error.

Comment: Which Operating system your are running the code?, try replacing ! with \! in sessionID/accessToken

Comment: Hi Sandy,Thanks for reply.I tried as you told,but it is giving same error.My operating system is linux.

Comment: I am not very good at java, but i found this http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/DemoREST.java, see if helps.

Comment: I would recommend using something similar to Fiddler or a different sniffing tool to see what is different between your two requests. Fiddler on Linux: http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono

Comment: Are you certain that your instance is na1? What is the instance_url in the OAuth response?